# I want to import something from a very high directory using sys

Tags: python, function, import, sys

Ok so the directories are on my D drive.

`MainApp/main.py` (The function which I want to import is in this file)

`MainApp/subfolder/thirdfolder/fourthfolder/thisissohard.py` (The file where I want to export the function to)

So I want to know how I can do this. I saw a tutorial on youtube but it only showed till the subdirectory but I want to go even deeper.

Any ideas?

Comment: `../../../main.py`

Comment: What have you tried? What did the YT tutorial show?

Comment: Well I actually haven't tried anything yet because I am still confused.
Here is the yt link: https://youtu.be/lR-OKnX7uOw

Comment: My answer may be incorrect; that said, try this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

For each folder, you need an `__init__.py` in that folder, for Python to recognize/treat it as a module, like the below imagined structure:

```
MainApp\
    .
    ├── main.py
    └── subfolder\
        ├── __init__.py
        └── thirdfolder\
            ├── __init__.py
            └── fourthfolder\
                ├── __init__.py
                └── thisissohard.py
```

Then, from `main.py` you can import like

`import subfolder.thirdfolder.fourthfolder.thisissohard`

or

`from subfolder.thirdfolder.fourthfolder.thisissohard import foo, bar`

*Source:* [SweetCode](https://sweetcode.io/python-file-importation-multi-level-directory-modules-packages/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sys.path.append()` you can add you project root to the path:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../../../../MainApp')

from MainApp.main import func
```